# Basic Directory / 'Text entry' create / delete / traversal (bash inspired) in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and functional programming and I did for training purpose a basic program where you can:

- create a directory (consisting of a name and an array of sub-directories)
- create an entry (consisting for a title and a content)
- remove and entry or a directory
- view an entry
- do a directory listing

The available commands are:

- ls
- cd *dir* or cd .. (to go to parent)
- mkdir *dirname*
- view *entry*
- exit
- help

Notes:

- There is not dependencies on Hackage (out of the box "The Haskell Platform" is enough).
- I corrected the source for hlint and now there is "no suggestions".

`

```
import Data.Maybe
import Data.List (sortBy,elemIndex,intercalate)
import Data.Function (on)
import System.IO (stdout,hFlush)
import System.Directory (doesFileExist)

-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
-- DATA and their functions
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

-- Ex:  - Directory { name = "dir1", directories = Directory { name = "dir2" } }
--      - path for dir2 will be ["dir2", "dir1"]
--      - getCurrentDirectory function get 'root Directory' + 'path' and return the directory at 'path'


data Entry = Entry { title :: String
                    ,content :: String } deriving (Show, Read)

data Directory = Directory { name :: String,
                             directories :: [Directory],
                             entries :: [Entry] } deriving (Show, Read)

-- Add an entry into the directory tree.
addEntry :: Directory -> [String] -> Entry -> Directory
addEntry dir [] newEntry = addDirectoryEntry dir newEntry
addEntry dir path newEntry = replaceDirectoryInPath dir (tail path) $ addDirectoryEntry currentDir newEntry
    where currentDir = getCurrentDirectory dir path

-- Add a directory into the directory tree.
addDirectory :: Directory -> [String] -> Directory -> Directory
addDirectory dir [] newDir = addDirectoryDirectory dir newDir
addDirectory dir path newDir = replaceDirectoryInPath dir (tail path) $ addDirectoryDirectory currentDir newDir
    where currentDir = getCurrentDirectory dir path

-- Remove an entry from the directory tree.
removeEntry :: Directory -> [String] -> Entry -> Directory
removeEntry dir [] e = removeDirectoryEntry dir e
removeEntry dir path e = replaceDirectoryInPath dir (tail path) $ removeDirectoryEntry currentDir e
    where currentDir = getCurrentDirectory dir path

-- Remove a directory from the directory tree.
removeDirectory :: Directory -> [String] -> Directory -> Directory
removeDirectory dir [] d = removeDirectoryDirectory dir d
removeDirectory dir path d = replaceDirectoryInPath dir (tail path) $ removeDirectoryDirectory currentDir d
    where currentDir = getCurrentDirectory dir path

-- Add an entry in a directory
addDirectoryEntry :: Directory -> Entry -> Directory
addDirectoryEntry dir e = Directory {
        name = name dir,
        directories = directories dir,
        entries = sortBy (compare `on` title) (e : entries dir)
    }

-- Add a directory in a directory
addDirectoryDirectory :: Directory -> Directory -> Directory
addDirectoryDirectory dir d = Directory {
        name = name dir,
        directories = sortBy (compare `on` name) (d : directories dir),
        entries = entries dir
    }

-- Remove an entry from a directory
removeDirectoryEntry :: Directory -> Entry -> Directory
removeDirectoryEntry dir e = Directory {
        name = name dir,
        directories = directories dir,
        entries = filter ((title e /= ) . title) (entries dir)
    }

-- Remove a directory from a directory
removeDirectoryDirectory :: Directory -> Directory -> Directory
removeDirectoryDirectory dir d = Directory {
        name = name dir,
        directories = filter ((name d /= ) . name) (directories dir),
        entries = entries dir
    }

-- Replace a directory in the specified path
-- Input: dir "xxx/yyy/zzz" "aaa"
-- Does: dir' = xxx/yyy/aaa
-- Returns: dir'
replaceDirectoryInPath :: Directory -> [String] -> Directory -> Directory
replaceDirectoryInPath dir [] newDir = addDirectoryDirectory (removeDirectoryDirectory dir newDir) newDir
replaceDirectoryInPath dir path newDir =
    replaceDirectoryInPath dir (tail path) $ addDirectoryDirectory (removeDirectoryDirectory currentDir newDir) newDir
    where currentDir = getCurrentDirectory dir path

-- Return the last directory specified by path
-- dir "xxx/yyy/zzz" returns zzz
getCurrentDirectory :: Directory -> [String] -> Directory
getCurrentDirectory dir [] = dir
getCurrentDirectory dir path = getCurrentDirectory (fromJust (getDirectory dir (last path))) (init path)

-- Return entry from dir by name
getEntry :: Directory -> String -> Maybe Entry
getEntry dir s = if length e > 0 then Just $ head e else Nothing
    where e = filter ((== s) . title) (entries dir)

-- Return directory from dir by name
getDirectory :: Directory -> String -> Maybe Directory
getDirectory dir s = if length d > 0 then Just $ head d else Nothing
    where d = filter ((== s) . name) (directories dir)

-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
-- The application
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let filename = "EntryBook.dat"
    dir <- loadData filename

    ls dir
    newDir <- prompt dir []

    saveData filename newDir
    return ()

-- Prompt
prompt :: Directory -> [String] -> IO Directory
prompt dir path = do    

    putStr "/"
    putStr $ intercalate "/" (reverse path)
    putStr "$ "
    hFlush stdout
    userInput <- getLine

    case strip userInput of
        "exit"  -> return dir
        ""      -> prompt dir path
        xd      -> do
            (msg, newDir, newPath) <- dispatch (strip userInput) dir path
            if msg == "" 
                then do
                    ls $ getCurrentDirectory newDir newPath
                    prompt newDir newPath
                else do
                    putStrLn msg
                    prompt newDir newPath

    where currentDir = getCurrentDirectory dir path

-- Dispatch user commands
dispatch :: String -> Directory -> [String] -> IO (String, Directory, [String])
dispatch "ls" dir path = do
    itemsNr <- ls currentDir
    return (show itemsNr ++ " element(s) found", dir, path)
    where currentDir = getCurrentDirectory dir path
dispatch ('c':'d':' ':s) (dir) (path) = do
    let (msg, newPath) = cd dir path s
    return (msg, dir, newPath)
dispatch ('v':'i':'e':'w':' ':xs) (dir) (path) = do
    let e = getEntry currentDir xs
    if isJust e
        then do
            displayEntry $ fromJust e
            return ("", dir, path)
        else
            return (xs ++ ": no such entry", dir, path)
    where currentDir = getCurrentDirectory dir path
dispatch "new" dir path = do
    e <- newEntry
    let newDir = addEntry dir path e
    return ("", newDir, path)
dispatch ('m':'k':'d':'i':'r':' ':xs) (dir) (path) = do
    let newDir = addDirectory dir path $ Directory xs [] []
    return ("", newDir, path)
dispatch ('r':'m':' ':xs) (dir) (path) = return $ rm dir path xs
dispatch "help" dir path = do
    help
    return ("", dir, path)
dispatch xs dir path = return (xs ++ ": command not found\nType 'help' for all available commands.", dir, path)

-- Directory listing
ls :: Directory -> IO Int
ls dir = do
    putStrLn $ "Directory name: " ++ name dir
    putStrLn "Directory listing:"
    mapM_ (\a -> putStrLn ("d| " ++ name a)) (directories dir)
    mapM_ (\a -> putStrLn ("e| " ++ title a)) (entries dir)
    return $ length (directories dir) + length (entries dir)

-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
-- The functions
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
-- Change directory
cd :: Directory -> [String] -> String -> (String, [String])
cd dir path dest =
    case dest of
        "/"  -> ("", [last path])
        ""   -> ("", path)
        "."  -> ("", path)
        ".." -> if length path > 0 then ("", tail path) else ("", path)
        xs   -> do
            let d = getDirectory (getCurrentDirectory dir path) xs
            if isJust d
                then
                    ("", name (fromJust d) : path)
                else
                    (xs ++ ": no such directory", path)

-- Remove an entry or a directory
rm :: Directory -> [String] -> String -> (String, Directory, [String])
rm dir path xs = do
    let d = getDirectory currentDir xs
    if isJust d
        then do
            let newDir = removeDirectory dir path $ fromJust d
            ("", newDir, path)
        else do
            let e = getEntry currentDir xs
            if isJust e
                then do
                    let newDir = removeEntry dir path $ fromJust e
                    ("", newDir, path)
                else
                    (xs ++ ": no such directory or entry", dir, path)
    where currentDir = getCurrentDirectory dir path

-- Print Help
help :: IO ()
help = do
    putStrLn "Available commands:"
    putStrLn "- exit: exit the application"
    putStrLn "- ls: list directory contents"
    putStrLn "- cd [dir]: change the current directory to dir"
    putStrLn "- mkdir [dir]: create a new directory [dir]"
    putStrLn "- view [entry]: display the content of entry"
    putStrLn "- new: open the entry creation screen"
    putStrLn "- help: display this help"

-- Create entry from user input
newEntry :: IO Entry
newEntry = do
    putStrLn "Entry title: "
    title <- getLine
    putStrLn "Entry content (type // to end): "
    content <- getMultilineText
    return $ Entry title content

-- Get multiline text from user input
getMultilineText :: IO String
getMultilineText = do
    text <- getLine
    if text == "//"
        then return ""
        else do
            newText <- getMultilineText
            return $ text ++ newText

-- Display an entry
displayEntry :: Entry -> IO ()
displayEntry e = do
        putStrLn ""
        putStrLn $ "Title: " ++ title e
        putStrLn "Content: "
        putStrLn $ content e
        exitOnInput <- getLine
        return ()

-- Save data to disk
saveData :: String -> Directory -> IO ()
saveData filename dir = do
    writeFile filename $ show dir
    return ()

-- Load data from disk
loadData :: String -> IO Directory
loadData filename = do
    fileExist <- doesFileExist filename
    if fileExist
        then do
            contents <- readFile filename
            let dir = read contents :: Directory
            return dir
        else return $ Directory "root" [] []

-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
-- Helper function
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
strip :: String -> String
strip = lstrip . rstrip

lstrip :: String -> String
lstrip = dropWhile (`elem` " \t")

rstrip :: String -> String
rstrip = reverse . lstrip . reverse

split :: Char -> String -> [String]
split delim [] = [""]
split delim (c:cs)
    | c == delim = "" : rest
    | otherwise = (c : head rest) : tail rest
   where
        rest = split delim cs
```

I would be pleased with any advises concerning the data structure, the code style or anything else. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few things that could be done in your code.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, ViewPatterns #-}
```

I use template haskell to derive data lenses, which make your directory access a little more succinct. I also use ViewPatterns so that the dispatch on string prefixes are easier.

```
import Data.Maybe
import Data.List (sortBy,groupBy,elemIndex,intercalate,stripPrefix)
import Data.Function (on)
import System.IO (stdout,hFlush)
import System.Directory (doesFileExist)
import Control.Monad

import Control.Applicative

import Data.Lens.Template (makeLenses)
import Data.Lens.Lazy
```

Notice the underscores in member names, these are converted to their lense equivalents by makeLenses

```
data Entry = Entry { _title :: String, _content :: String }
  deriving (Show, Read)

data Directory = Directory 
       { _name :: String, _directories :: [Directory], _entries :: [Entry] }
  deriving (Show, Read)

$( makeLenses [''Directory, ''Entry])
```

These few functions are tight. There is nothing more to be done with them I think. However, it should be noted that Entry and Directory have complementary functions everywhere. Perhaps it is profitable to abstract the common skeleton.

```
-- Add an entry into the directory tree.
addEntry :: Directory -> [String] -> Entry -> Directory
addEntry dir [] newEntry = addDirectoryEntry dir newEntry
addEntry dir path newEntry = replaceDirectoryInPath dir (tail path) 
                               $ addDirectoryEntry currentDir newEntry
    where currentDir = getCurrentDirectory dir path

-- Add a directory into the directory tree.
addDirectory :: Directory -> [String] -> Directory -> Directory
addDirectory dir [] newDir = addDirectoryDirectory dir newDir
addDirectory dir path newDir = replaceDirectoryInPath dir (tail path) 
                              $ addDirectoryDirectory currentDir newDir
    where currentDir = getCurrentDirectory dir path

-- Remove an entry from the directory tree.
removeEntry :: Directory -> [String] -> Entry -> Directory
removeEntry dir [] e = removeDirectoryEntry dir e
removeEntry dir path e = replaceDirectoryInPath dir (tail path) 
                              $ removeDirectoryEntry currentDir e
    where currentDir = getCurrentDirectory dir path

-- Remove a directory from the directory tree.
removeDirectory :: Directory -> [String] -> Directory -> Directory
removeDirectory dir [] d = removeDirectoryDirectory dir d
removeDirectory dir path d = replaceDirectoryInPath dir (tail path) 
                          $ removeDirectoryDirectory currentDir d
    where currentDir = getCurrentDirectory dir path
```

We start getting use out of the lenses here. Compare it to your code.

```
-- Add an entry in a directory
addDirectoryEntry :: Directory -> Entry -> Directory
addDirectoryEntry dir e = entries ^%= (sortBy (compare `on` _title)) . (e :) $ dir

-- Add a directory in a directory
addDirectoryDirectory :: Directory -> Directory -> Directory
addDirectoryDirectory dir d = directories ^%= (sortBy (compare `on` _name)) . (d :) $ dir

-- Remove an entry from a directory
removeDirectoryEntry :: Directory -> Entry -> Directory
removeDirectoryEntry dir e =  entries ^%= (filter ((_title e /=) . _title)) $ dir

-- Remove a directory from a directory
removeDirectoryDirectory :: Directory -> Directory -> Directory
removeDirectoryDirectory dir d =  directories ^%= (filter ((_name d /=) . _name)) $ dir

-- Replace a directory in the specified path
-- Input: dir "xxx/yyy/zzz" "aaa"
-- Does: dir' = xxx/yyy/aaa
-- Returns: dir'
replaceDirectoryInPath :: Directory -> [String] -> Directory -> Directory
replaceDirectoryInPath dir [] newDir = addDirectoryDirectory 
                          (removeDirectoryDirectory dir newDir) newDir
replaceDirectoryInPath dir path newDir =
    replaceDirectoryInPath dir (tail path) 
       $ addDirectoryDirectory (removeDirectoryDirectory currentDir newDir) newDir
    where currentDir = getCurrentDirectory dir path

-- Return the last directory specified by path
-- dir "xxx/yyy/zzz" returns zzz
getCurrentDirectory :: Directory -> [String] -> Directory
getCurrentDirectory dir [] = dir
getCurrentDirectory dir path = getCurrentDirectory 
                      $ fromJust (getDirectory dir (last path))) (init path)

-- Return entry from dir by name
getEntry :: Directory -> String -> Maybe Entry
getEntry dir s = if length e > 0 then Just $ head e else Nothing
    where e = filter ((== s) . _title) (_entries dir)

-- Return directory from dir by name
getDirectory :: Directory -> String -> Maybe Directory
getDirectory dir s = if length d > 0 then Just $ head d else Nothing
    where d = filter ((== s) . _name) (_directories dir)

-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
-- The application
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
filename = "EntryBook.dat"

main :: IO ()
main = loadData filename >>= (\dir -> ls dir >> prompt dir []) >>= saveData filename

-- Prompt
prompt :: Directory -> [String] -> IO Directory
prompt dir path = do    
    putStr $ concat ["/",intercalate "/" (reverse path), "$ "]
    hFlush stdout
    userInput <- getLine

    case strip userInput of
        "exit"  -> return dir
        ""      -> prompt dir path
        xd      -> domore dir path xd 
    where currentDir = getCurrentDirectory dir path
          domore dir path xd = do
            (msg, newDir, newPath) <- dispatch xd dir path
            if msg == "" then
                (ls $ getCurrentDirectory newDir newPath) >> return ()
                else putStrLn msg
            prompt newDir newPath
```

With ViewPatterns, we can match on string prefixes

```
-- Dispatch user commands
dispatch :: String -> Directory -> [String] -> IO (String, Directory, [String])
dispatch "ls" dir path = do
    itemsNr <- ls currentDir
    return (show itemsNr ++ " element(s) found", dir, path)
    where currentDir = getCurrentDirectory dir path
dispatch (stripPrefix "cd " -> Just xs) dir path = return (msg, dir, newPath)
   where (msg, newPath) = cd dir path xs
dispatch (stripPrefix "view " -> Just xs) dir path = case getEntry currentDir xs of
      Just x -> displayEntry x >> return ("", dir, path)
      _ -> return (xs ++ ": no such entry", dir, path)
   where currentDir = getCurrentDirectory dir path
dispatch "new" dir path = newEntry >>= \e -> return ("", addEntry dir path e, path)
dispatch (stripPrefix "mkdir " -> Just xs) dir path = return ("", newDir, path)
    where newDir = addDirectory dir path $ Directory xs [] []
dispatch (stripPrefix "rm " -> Just xs) dir path = return $ rm dir path xs
dispatch "help" dir path = help >> return ("", dir, path)
dispatch xs dir path = return (xs ++ 
       ": command not found\nType 'help' for all available commands.", dir, path)
```

Notice the reduction in code for the dispatched commands.

```
-- Directory listing
ls :: Directory -> IO Int
ls dir = do
    putStrLn $ "Directory name: " ++ (_name dir)
    putStrLn "Directory listing:"
    mapM_ (putStrLn . ("d| " ++) . _name) $ _directories dir
    mapM_ (putStrLn . ("e| " ++) . _title) $ _entries dir
    return $ length (_directories dir) + length (_entries dir)

-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
-- The functions
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
-- Change directory
cd :: Directory -> [String] -> String -> (String, [String])
cd dir path dest =
    case dest of
        "/"  -> ("", [last path])
        ""   -> ("", path)
        "."  -> ("", path)
        ".." -> ("", if null path then path else tail path)
        xs   -> case getDirectory (getCurrentDirectory dir path) xs of
                Just x -> ("", _name x : path)
                Nothing -> (xs ++ ": no such directory", path)

-- Remove an entry or a directory
rm :: Directory -> [String] -> String -> (String, Directory, [String])
rm dir path xs = fromMaybe (xs ++ ": no such directory or entry", dir, path)
    $ myfn (getDirectory, removeDirectory) `mplus` myfn (getEntry, removeEntry)
 where currentDir = getCurrentDirectory dir path
       myfn (fna, fnb) = fna currentDir xs >>= \x -> return ("", fnb dir path x, path)
```

We can profitably use unlines to simulate heredocs in haskell.

```
-- Print Help
help :: IO ()
help = putStrLn $ unlines [
    "Available commands:",
    "- exit: exit the application",
    "- ls: list directory contents",
    "- cd [dir]: change the current directory to dir",
    "- mkdir [dir]: create a new directory [dir]",
    "- view [entry]: display the content of entry",
    "- new: open the entry creation screen",
    "- help: display this help"]

-- Create entry from user input
newEntry :: IO Entry
newEntry = getPromptLine "Entry title: " <*
           putStrLn "Entry content (type // to end): " >>= (<$> getMultilineText) . Entry


getPromptLine :: String -> IO String
getPromptLine prompt = putStrLn prompt >> getLine 

-- Get multiline text from user input
getMultilineText :: IO String
getMultilineText = getLine >>= checkEnd
  where checkEnd "//" = return []
        checkEnd t = (++) t <$> getMultilineText

-- Display an entry
displayEntry :: Entry -> IO ()
displayEntry e = putStrLn (unlines ["", "Title: " ++ (_title e),
    "Content: ", _content e]) >> getLine >> return ()

-- Save data to disk
saveData :: String -> Directory -> IO ()
saveData filename dir = writeFile filename $ show dir

-- Load data from disk
loadData :: String -> IO Directory
loadData filename = check =<< doesFileExist filename
  where check True = read <$> readFile filename
        check False = return $ Directory "root" [] []

-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
-- Helper function
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
strip :: String -> String
strip = lstrip . rstrip

lstrip :: String -> String
lstrip = dropWhile (`elem` " \t")

rstrip :: String -> String
rstrip = reverse . lstrip . reverse
```